# Print vs printing vs print design tags

Tags: discussion

Simple question / task. I was going to add some kind of print process related tag to this interesting question: [How to prepare a layout for packaging and hot stamping?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13189/how-to-prepare-a-layout-for-packaging-and-hot-stamping)

I saw we've got these three print related tags:

- **Print**. 67 questions, no description
- **Printing**. 41 questions, no description
- **Print-design**. 90 questions, *"Printing is a process for reproducing text and image, typically with ink on paper using a printing press. It is often carried out as a large-scale industrial process, and is an essential part of publishing and transaction printing."*

Clearly some merging and clarifying needs to happen.

(there's also a very lonely looking:

- **Prepress** 2 questions, no description

)

---

What should our range of print tags be?

Comment: You should really put the suggestion part as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

- **Print-design**. *For questions about crafting a design that will be printed on physical materials*
- **Print-process**. *For questions about the mechanical process of industrial printing, as it relates to design work: including standard offset presses (sheet and web) plus less common print processes like screen printing. Individual processes can have their own tags in addition to this.*
- **Print-prepress**. *For questions about the process of preparing design work for industrial printing*
- (new) **Print-desktop**. *For questions about creating and optimising designs intended for home or office printers or photocopiers (NOT for 'my printer's broken help me fix it'!)*

(not sure how to word those as appropriate tag summaries, just writing like that so you get the idea)

---

Rationale: Print design questions will be of interest to any designer who designs for print. Print process questions will be of interest to those designers who take an active interest in the process and mechanics of printing (some prefer to delegate that stuff, some love to tinker and understand each detail): then you can also create tags where needed for specific processes. Print prepress spans a range of specific closely related tasks. Print-desktop covers a range of similar niche cases - e.g. people who create PDFs for public download.

---

(moved to an answer as per e100's suggestion)

Comment: Good suggestion, but how would you tag home/office printing? Do you need another tag? Edit: just remembered I already asked about this: http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/64/tagging-how-to-differentiate-professional-printing-and-everyday-printing?rq=1

Comment: @e100 Editted (a few days ago and then forgot). End result is almost exactly the same as the one you came up independently a year ago, which seems well-upvoted. Any idea how to make it actually happen?

Answer (score 0):

**`Print-Design`** is adequate to encapsulate all of the above.

**`Printing-Process`** could be used to clarify those questions that are really about running paper through a press.

In reality, any graphic design post that is worthy of tagging `Print` should probably be `prepress` or `bindery`. And restating `design` seems redundant on a graphic *design* board. But, as the tags indicate, people think of "print design" when they start adding tags so we might as well support that.